# Bundle and rake commands are not recognized with Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3

I have installed Capistrano 3 and I'm not able to get my app to call `bundle install` and precompile my assets on deploy.

I've seen that I have to configure my environment for RVM there http://rvm.io/deployment/capistrano#environment

But I was wondering, I have a dev computer A, and a deployment computer B, which both have RVM user-installed.

Should I configure Capistrano to use RVM on my dev computer or on the deployment computer?

Comment: Capistrano uses SSH on your dev machine to run commands on the deployment machine, except for anything in a `run_locally` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Capfile have the following?

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
```

capistrano/rails includes dependencies for bundler, assets and migrations.

https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/rails.rb
https://github.com/capistrano/rvm

Also make sure to read the readme on capistrano/rvm, as you need to have the correct capistrano/bundler version.